# Lable Text Alway Gray when show

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have a form in VB.net with only a label and progress bar.  In design mode I can make the label text any color I want.  But when I use the form in my app to show to progress of something the text is always grey.  I have even tried to change it with code, but the text in the label is always grey.  I can't figure out why.

Comment: Is the `Enabled` property set to `False`?

Comment: Yes it was.  Changing back to true fixed the issue.  thanks